# WSAECONNREFUSED SAP Gui unable to connect on SAP server on hp ux - inetd.conf file reference

Tags: unix, tcp, hp-ux, sap, inetd

I have a sap server installed on  HP-UX vm, up and running.
when I try to connect to the server from SAP client GUI installed on windows machine I get the following error

```
---------------------------
SAP GUI for Windows 730
---------------------------
partner '15.213.245.61:sapdp00' not reached

Time        Thu Dec 11 02:59:48 2014
Component   NI (network interface)
Release     730
Version     40
Module      nixxi.cpp
Line        3286
Method      NiPConnect2: 15.213.245.61:3200
Return Code -10
System Call connect
Error   No  10061
Error   Text    WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
Counter     1

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I looked through and found out that the hp-ux server port 3200 was inaccessible.

the /etc/services file contains an entry

```
sapdp00   3200/tcp
```

but in /etc/inetd.config file no corresponding entry is present.

so to test whether this is the root cause, I edited the /etc/inetd.conf file, added following entry

```
sapdp00  stream tcp nowait root testservice.sh TEST
```

and did a inetd -c

this time when I tried to connect from the sap gui client on windows I got a different error,

```
---------------------------
SAP GUI for Windows 730
---------------------------
connection to partner '15.213.245.61:sapdp00' broken

Time        Thu Dec 11 03:08:52 2014
Component   NI (network interface)
Release     730
Version     40
Module      nixxi.cpp
Line        5087
Method      NiIRead: P=15.213.245.61:3200; L=0.0.0.0:50410
Return Code -6
System Call recv
Error   No  10053
Error   Text    WSAECONNABORTED: Software caused connection abort
Counter     1

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

while the earlier error indicated connection refused, this one indicated that a connection was established and then aborted.( maybe due to improper entry against services path in inetd.conf file)

I think that if I can provide a proper path for sapdp00 service in the entry to the location where the actual service exists then maybe this error would be eliminated.
my questions..
is this diagnosis correct?
if yes,  shouldn't the entry in inetd.conf file should have been made automatically during sap installation process?  why not..?
how to find the correct path for sapdp00 service?

kindly advise,

EDIT- not sure about this but found three processes running

```
# ps -ex | grep sap
 18132 pts/0     0:00 grep sap
 10885 ?         0:00 /usr/sap/E64/DVEBMGS00/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/E64/SYS/profile/START_DVEBMGS00_hpvm-202 -D -u e64adm
 13214 ?         0:10 /usr/sap/E64/SYS/exe/run/saposcol
 11059 ?         0:00 /usr/sap/E64/D01/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/E64/SYS/profile/START_D01_hpvm-202 -D -u e64adm
```

can any one of the paths be used..I am not sure which service is mapped with sapdp00...

Comment: How did you jump from connection refused to 'inetd should be running this'?  I'm not saying it shouldn't.. I don't really know, but there are very few things that run out of inetd these days.  Back up, find out exactly what exact process should be on that port, then move forward.  Your troubleshooting was on target until that point where you jumped the rails.  And if you pay SAP, you should be talking to them.

Comment: If you look at the error, it says trying access at port 3200. so next logical step was to check whether this port was accessible?
and I checked and it wasn't. so next step was to check if there are any services that should be mapped to this port ? ans /etc/services -> sapdp 3200
but /etc/services only lists the services. mapping is actually present in inetd.conf file.

to check the above diagnosis I edited the inetd.conf file and connection was accepted and then aborted(as outlined in question)

Comment: Correct!  That was the last part that made sense if you're trying to follow the process linearly.  What makes you think inetd should be running the process that should be listening on port 3200?

Comment: acc to wiki "inetd (internet service daemon) is a super-server daemon on many Unix systems that provides Internet services. For each configured service, it listens for requests from connecting clients." do you know of any other file that aides in this?

Comment: `do you know of any other file that aides in this?`  Yes.  Every single application on the planet that has been designed to run as a standalone daemon. There are thousands of them.

Comment: what I meant was that are you aware of any other file which might have the path details or lists the services listening to particular port the way inetd.conf file does?? especially for sap.

Comment: After thinking for a few minutes.. Outside of inetd.. it's possible that init (/etc/inittab) could run it but I don't think that's very common anymore.  Likely it is a standalone daemon that's supposed to be started while the system is booting up or it does not get started automatically at all and you need to run a script to start it.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar at all with SAP and haven't touched HP-UX in about 8 years.  I can't be any more specific.  About the wiki / inetd earlier... It's not necessarily wrong, it's just outdated.  Very few things start up via inetd these days.

Comment: can we please preserve "How did you jump from connection refused to 'inetd should be running this'" for posterity... in a running SAP system, the disp+work binary will listen on 32xx/tcp where xx=instance number (a number between 0 and 99). It will be symlinked, and appear in ps output as dw.sap<SID>_<INSTANCE>. Oh, and yes, it's started not by inetd, but by the sapstart service, which you saw running above.

Answer (score 1):

My troubleshoot steps are:

1. Install `SAP GUI` locally inside the guest `VMware` that the `SAP` server is running and test connection to local host
2. Install `SAP GUI` in the host that the VMware is running and try connection to localhost or same IP
3. Install `SAP GUI` in the vlan to be sure routing and port forwarding is working good with NAT configuration and client/remote access configuration.

It is necessary to verify if you:
a-set up the loopback network interface correctly and be sure you added an entry to hosts file of the server:

```
192.168.25.25 SAPECC60
```

b-be sure in SAP MMC (management console) you have successfully started the `SAP` services and all servers look green
c-firewall is allowing TCP for port range `3200-3299` to be passed in the server
d-the NAT includes at a minimum the two ports `3200` and `3299` (not necessarily the full range is needed to be declared one by one in the nat config of VMware app)

Other than that, the full installation of the SAP must be reviewed and it will be necessary to discuss in more details. if you need extra help, please let me know.